# Isometry between finite-dimensional space and its topological dual

Tags: functional-analysis, vector-spaces

> Let $(X, \|\cdot \|_X)$ be a normed, finite dimensional vector space. Show that its topological dual $X'$ is isometrically isomorphic to $X$.

The general form of such a linear map between those spaces should be: $$l : X \to X', x_o \mapsto l_{x_o} :=x_0^T A$$ for an $A \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$ with $\dim X = n$, and $l_{x_0}(x) = x_0^T A x$ (representing $x_0$ and $x$ in $\mathbb{R}^n$, which should be possible by isomorphy). For this to be an isometry, I tried to find $A$ such that
$$\|x_0\|_X \stackrel{!}{=} \|l_{x_0}\| = \sup_{x \in X \setminus \{0\}} \frac{|x_0^T A x|}{\|x\|_X},$$
the latter terms being the operator norm. If all my assumptions up to this point are correct, this should eventually lead me to the solution, but I just cannot come up with any information about the matrix $A$ that I need to find. It's probably really easy, but I just started on the subject.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Which norm do you consider on $X'$? For the *dual  norm* $\|x'\|'=\sup\lbrace |x'(x)|: \|x\|\le 1\rbrace$ the statement does not seem to be true: the dual $(\mathbb R^2,\|\cdot\|_p)$ with $\|(x,y)\|_p= (|x|^p+|y|^p)^{1/p}$ is $\|\cdot\|_p'=\|\cdot\|_q$ with the conjugate exponent $q$ (i.e., $1/p+1/q=1$).

Comment: @Jochen: It is true that the norm on the dual space is different from the norm on the original space. But does this imply that we can not construct a suitable isomorphism (which does not necessarily coincide with the "usual duality" given by $\langle \cdot , \cdot \rangle$) which nevertheless happens to be isometric?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Okay, after some more research and thought, this statement seems to be **wrong**. Some proofs I've seen now argue equivalency of norms, which just doesn't work when you explicitly try to apply it; equivalency of norms is only useful when you talk about inequalities of norms. In general, $\|x\|_a = \|y\|_a  \nRightarrow \|x\|_b = \|y\|_b$ even when the norms are equivalent (consider for example $(1,1),(1,0) \in \mathbb{R}^2$ with the sup norm and the $1$-Norm).

$(\mathbb{R}^2 , \|\cdot\|_p)$ with its dual space $(\mathbb{R}^2, \|\cdot \|_q)$ (with $\frac{1}{p} + \frac{1}{q} = 1$ ) provieds a counterexample for $p,q \notin \{ 1, 2, \infty \}$, as these spaces can never be isometric. The proof is a little difficult, but can be found [here](http://matematicas.unex.es/~fcabello/files/printable/01.pdf).

An intuitive approach: A linear map between two unit circles needs to conserve the "corners", that means for $p,q \notin \{ 1, 2, \infty \}$ for example $(1,0)$ would need to be mapped to $(\pm 1, 0)$ or $(0, \pm 1)$, as this is where the "corners" on the respective unit circles are placed. For $p \in \{ 1, \infty\} \implies q \in \{\infty, 1\}$ this is not a problem: Both unit circles are squares, which can be transformed into each other by rotation and scaling, and the case $p = 2 \implies q = 2$ is trivial. 
But in all the other cases, this "preserving corners" condition gives us a contradiction when we map the standard basis $\{(1,0), (0,1)\}$ to any of the possibilites, because then the other points on the circle will not be mapped correctly.

Answer (score 1):

X is finite dimensional. Suppose $A=\{x_1,...,x_n\}$ is its basis. Define $l_i:X\to \Bbb C$ such that $l_i(x_j)=\delta_{ij}$ for $x_j\in A$. Clearly $l_i$ is linear and bounded(X is finite dimensional). Show that $\{l_i\}$ is a basis for $X^*$.

Define $\phi:X\to X^*$ such that $\phi(x)=l_x$. Every $x\in X$ has the representation $x=\sum_{I=1}^n \alpha_i x_i$, so $l_x= \sum_{I=1}^n \alpha_il_i$. Clearly $\phi$ is an isomorphism. To show it's an isometry, we know all norms are equivalent in finite dimensional space. Thus using $||.||_\infty$, we have $\|x\|=\|l_x\|$.

Comment: Can you really argue equivalence of norms here? If $\frac{1}{C} \| x \|_\infty \leq \| x \| \leq C \| x \|_\infty$, then $\| x \|_\infty = \| l_x \|_\infty$ only implies $ \frac{1}{C^2} \| x \| \leq \|l_x\| \leq C^2 \|x \|$, which is not the needed equality. Am I missing something crucial?

Comment: @LukasMiristwhisky : X is a normed space by its norm $\|.\|$.we have $\|x\|_\infty= \sup|\alpha_i|=\|l_x\|_\infty$. I mean because X is finite dimensional,$\|.\|$ is equivalent to $\|.\|_\infty$. Now we have $\|x\|=\|x\|_\infty=\|l_x\|_\infty=\|l_x\|$.

Comment: But isn't the definition of equivalence of two norms $\| \cdot \|_a, \| \cdot \|_b$ on $X$ that there exists some constant $C > 0$ with $\frac{1}{C} \| x \|_a \leq \|c \|_b \leq C \| x \| _b$ for all $x \in X$? This would only justify $\| x \|_a = \| x \|_b$ if $C = 1$, which we do not necessarily have.

Comment: @LukasMiristwhisky : Your definition is correct. What is norm on X?

Comment: You can not just **use/pick** the norm $\Vert \cdot \Vert_\infty$. The norm $\Vert \cdot \Vert_X$ is given (fixed, cou can not choose it) and this norm uniquely determines the norm $\Vert \varphi \Vert_{X'} = \sup_{\Vert x \Vert_X = 1} |\varphi(x)|$. The way I understand the question, we want the isomorphism to be isometric with respect to these norms. Hence, you can not just choose a norm that suits you.