# Vector spaces isomorphic to its dual

Tags: hilbert-spaces, banach-spaces, duality-theorems

Let $X$ be a finite-dimensional normed vector space. Is there an isometry $L:X\to X^*$? I know there is an isomorphism. I guess it's not true for all spaces, but I wonder on which conditions it is true. More precisely, I'm looking for conditions on a Banach $E$ to have: each finite-dimensional subspace of $E$ satisfies the property.

Comment: I didn't read it very carefully, but [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1017728/isometry-between-finite-dimensional-space-and-its-topological-dual) might be useful to you.

Answer (score 2):

Observe that $(\ell^n_p)^* =\ell^n_q$, where $1/p+1/q=1$. Therefore it isn't true that the dual is always isometric. It's true for $p=2$ and generally if the space is Hilbert. If $p=1$ or $p=\infty$ then it's also true but only if $n=2$ (balls are rectangles). It's sufficient that the balls in both spaces are similar (actually, more generally, affine equivalent, as Ilya Bogdanov observed) (recall that the unit ball determine the norm). It is related to the notion od [dual polyhedra](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dual_polyhedron): if the ball is a polyhedron (of some dimension) then the ball in the dual space is a dual polyhedron.

Comment: It suffices for the ball to be affine equivalent to its dual.

Comment: Thank you, can you direct me to a definition of "affine equivalent"? I can't find any

Comment: Two sets are affine equivalent if there exists the affine function (bijection) such that one set is the image of the other. Similarly, two sets are congruent if there exists an isometry such that one set is the image of the other set. Two sets have the same cardinality if there exists a bijection such that..., and so on.